# Passing values into a c++ Class constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop

Overview of program feature:
I am required to write a program that asks the users to input the size of the array. This size will then be sent to a class function. The class function will then create a dynamic array with this size.

This is what I have so far.

IIntsArray.h

```
    class IIntsArray 
{
   public:
    int sizeOfArray;
    int *array;
    IIntsArray();

    void setSizeOfArray(int);
};
```

IIntsArray.cpp

```
#include "IIntsArray.h"

IIntsArray::IIntsArray() 
{
    cout << "Default constructor" << endl;
}

void IIntsArray::setSizeOfArray(int s)
{

    s = sizeOfArray;
    array = new int[s];

    cout << "size is: " << s << endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "IIntsArray.h"

    int main() {
    IIntsArray object;
    int size;
    cout << "Enter size: " << endl;
    cin >> size;

    object.setSizeOfArray(size);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is as follows:

```
Default constructor
Enter size: 
5
size is: 0

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 1s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

The output I am trying to get is:

```
Default constructor
Enter size:
5
size is: 5
```

Comment: because you need `sizeOfArray=s`

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to: `int main() { int a, b; cin >> a; a = b; cout << a << "\n"; }`

Comment: Pretty sure `sizeOfArray = s` will give you much better results...

Comment: perreal and Jean, both your answers worked. I feel so stupid I missed out this tiny mistake.. thanks again

Comment: Such classes do not need to be written. Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: @msafar95 your question title is misleading.

Comment: Use a debugger to find such errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s = sizeOfArray;` would not work because you are setting s to 0. `sizeOfArray = s;` would solve your problem.